# String divisibility without search tables?

Tags: python, string, division

> Given two strings s & t, determine if s is divisible by t. For
> example: "abab" is divisible by "ab" But "ababab" is not divisible by
> "abab". If it isn't divisible, return -1. If it is, return the length
> of the smallest common divisor: So, for "abababab" and "abab", return
> 2 as s is divisible  by t and the smallest common divisor is "ab" with
> length 2.

The way I thought it through was: I define the lengths of these two strings, find the greatest common divisor of these two. If t divides s, then the smallest common divisor is just the smallest divisor of t. And then one can use this algorithm: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm.

Is there any simpler solution?

Comment: What language are you writing this in, and why are you doing it? Any string search you write manually in Python is going to have a massive constant-factor overhead.

Comment: Python, I actually saw the question here on StackOverflow but only on the theoretical level, the algorithm makes sense to me but I have trouble with the implementation.

Answer (score 1):

To test for divisibility:

1. test that the length of s is a multiple of the length of t (otherwise not divisible);
2. divide s into chunks of length t; and
3. check that all the chunks are the same.

To find the smallest common divisor, you need to find the shortest repeating substring of t that makes up the whole of t.  One approach is:

1. Find the factors of the length of t (the crude approach of searching from 1 up to sqrt(len(t)) should be fine for strings of any reasonable length);
2. For each factor (start with the smallest):

   i. divide t into chunks of length factor;

   ii. check if all the chunks are the same, and return factor if they are.

Using a Python set is a neat way to check if all the chunks in a list are equal.  len(set(chunks)) == 1 tells you they are.

Answer (score -1):

The GCD of the string lengths doesn't help you.

A string `t` "divides" a string `s` if `len(s)` is a multiple of `len(t)` and `s == t * (len(s)//len(t))`.

As for finding the length of the smallest divisor of `t`, the classic trick for that is `(t+t).index(t, 1)`: find the first nonzero index of `t` in `t+t`. I've used the built-in `index` method here, but depending on why you're doing this and what runtime properties you want, KMP string search may be a better choice. Manually implementing KMP in Python is going to have a massive constant-factor overhead, but it'll have a much better worst-case runtime than `index`.

KMP isn't particularly hard to implement, as far as string searches go. You're not going to get anything significantly "simpler" without delegating to a library routine or sacrificing asymptotic complexity properties (or both).

If you want to avoid a search table and keep asymptotic complexity guarantees, you can use something like [two-way string matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-way_string-matching_algorithm), but it's not going to be any easier to implement than KMP.